# Order Email - Use Order ID to get custom attribute

Tags: sales-order, order-email

In **order_new.html**, I am using `{{var order.getTest()}}` to try and get a custom order attribute (special instructions, purchase order, etc).  However, I need to pass the order id through to execute my code to return the variables.  How can I pass the order id to the function?

**Sales/Model/Order.php:**

```
public function getTest($orderid)
{
    $test = "THIS IS A TEST... ORDER ID: " . $orderid;
    return $test;
}
```

`{{var order.increment_id}}` prints the correct order id on the template of the email, however, when I try to add it to the above mentioned function, no value is being passed through.  Here's what I've tried on **order_new.phtml**:

- {{var order.getTest({{var order.increment_id}})}}
- {{var order.getTest(var order.increment_id}}
- {{var order.getTest({{order.increment_id}})}}
- {{var order.getTest(order.increment_id}}
- {{var order.getTest({{var order}})}}
- {{var order.getTest(var order}}
- {{var order.getTest({{order}})}}
- {{var order.getTest(order}}

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you need to pass the order id to a method that is inside the order model. Can't you just use `$this->getId()` inside `getTest` method, since you are getting the value for the current order?

Comment: @Marius Hmmm that's a good idea, however, it's returning a different order id, not the increment_id.

Comment: And $this->getOrderId() doesn't return a value.

Comment: getIncrementId() does work however.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **order_new.html**, use:

```
{{var order.getTest()}}
```

In **Sales/Model/Order.php**, use:

```
public function getTest()
{
    $orderid = $this->getIncrementId();
    $html = "TEST... The Order ID is: " . $orderid . ". Happy days!";
    return $html;
}
```

You can also use `getId()` which will return the non-increment order id.