# How to query data into email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates

Assume that I have **customer_code** in the `sales_order_detail` table. and I have created a view that store this column with **increment_id**.

How can I query that column into an email template by using **increment_id**?

I have called `"var order.increment_id |raw":"Order Id"` into template. but I don't know how to query the data in the template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/161053/77554

This might be needed to override the Magento/Sales/Model/Order.php

Please try your luck and let me know

Happy coding

Comment: Can I tried this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/251274/100320 to overide Order.php?

Comment: yes you can but pay attention to construct parameters and their orders